# Is the second 'for' loop necessary, and if so, why?

Tags: function, loops

```
I think that my confusion is also related to my misunderstanding of the tier definition. What purpose does the '' placeholder serve in defining the tier variable as such?

function printTriangle(length) {
    for(var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {

        var tier = '';

        for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            tier += '*';
        }

    console.log(tier);
   }
}
//printTriangle(3);


*
**
***
```

---

Additionally, how does adding a third loop make the output align to a pyramid like so? I've seen this utilized as a brainteaser/interview prompt but I would think that basic understanding (I'm just diving into this if you can't already tell) would make transitioning from the triangle to the pyramid fairly simple.

```
       *
      * *
     * * *
    * * * *
   * * * * *
  * * * * * *
 * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
```

---

---

```
function printPyramid(length) {
    for(var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        var tier = '';

        for(var j = length - i; j > 0; j--) {
            tier += ' ';
        }
        for(var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            tier += '* ';
        }
     console.log(tier);
    }
}
//printPyramid(10);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `''` placeholder is only used to initialize the `tier` variable as a string. Its value is never used until the loop is entered and actual characters are added.

Yes. The first loop takes care of rows. The second loop draws each level. Notice that the `j` loop uses `i` as an input parameter. In this case, the pyramid level (starting from the top) is equal to the width of the pyramid at that point.

Adding the third loop is not superfluous. What it does is add space characters so that the pyramid appears to have a centered top rather than a top that is flush against the left side of the screen.